# ADV is covering ListView item

Tags: android, listview, adview

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.christiangiupponi.flyingnerd.ChooseCharacter">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/secondaryLightRed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main_tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main_tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/main_tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5716601702418411/1068596445" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I run it on emulator or a device the ADV (`com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`) shows up but cover the last listview item.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a RelativeLayout and make android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" onto  AdView and android:layout_above="@+id/adView" onto my top level content view.

Comment: What to you mean with "top level content view"? My `AppBarLayout `?